# Selenium NUnit not represent Test cases in Test Expore

Tags: selenium-webdriver

1 - I am newly for Selenium ,When I am using NUnit ,Test cases are not represent in Test Explore ,and my code only pass [Setup] section. I already using VS2013 Express, NUnit 2.6.2 and NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework 0.95.0 ........

2 - Can't we use NUnit directly ,Is it required gallio-test-runner or not ???

Comment: Please add what have you done already, pieces of code...

Comment: public class Program
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()
        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.lk/webhp?hl=en");
            Console.WriteLine("Opened URL");
        }
        [Test]
        public void ExecuteTest()
        {
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("q"));
            element.SendKeys("executeautomation");
  
        }
        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            driver.Close();
      
        }

Comment: This is what I coded ...It simple serch in Google .....I can not see any test case in test Explore in VS 2013.I already install NUnit adapter and NUnit ...

Comment: Please add it to the question text and delete comments

Comment: No worries I think that NUnitTestAsapter new version  not compatibility with VS2013 ,When we are going to plug it ,it is say that version  for VS 2012.